# Unable to trigger build for tag based code push using Generic Webhook Trigger

Tags: git, jenkins, webhooks

#### Issue

Unable to trigger the build only for `TAG` based code checkout. Its initiating the build for both `BRANCH` and `TAG` based code checkout.

#### Version

- Jenkins: 2.401.1
- Plugin: 1.86.3

#### How to reproduce:

- Create a Jenkinsfile using the following code and create a build pipeline:

```
def val = "Jenkins-Agent-01"
def registryLogin = "docker-hub.example.com"
def imageURL = "centos/devops-build:latest" 

pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label val
            customWorkspace "/opt/devops/workspace/${JOB_NAME}/${BUILD_NUMBER}"
        }
    }
    triggers {
        GenericTrigger(
            genericVariables: [
            [key: 'eventKey', value: '$.eventKey', defaultValue: 'null'],
            [key: 'tagId', value: '$.changes[0].refId', defaultValue: 'null'],
            [key: 'repoName', value: '$.repository.name', defaultValue: 'null'],
            [key: 'repository_slug', value: '$.repository.slug', defaultValue: 'null'],
            [key: 'repository_project_key', value: '$.repository.project.key', defaultValue: 'null'],
            [key: 'changes_ref_ids', value: '$.changes[?(@.ref.type == "TAG")].ref.id', defaultValue: 'null']
            ],
            causeString: 'Triggered By BitBucket',
            token: '',
            tokenCredentialId: '',
            printContributedVariables: false,
            printPostContent: false,
            silentResponse: false,
            regexpFilterText: '$changes_ref_ids',
            regexpFilterExpression: '^refs/tags/.*$'
        )
    }

    stages {
        stage('Display Payload') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh """
                    echo "Repo ref Id: ${changes_ref_ids}"
                    echo "Repo Project Key: ${repository_project_key}"
                    """
                }            
            }
        }

        stage('Build Jar file') {
            steps {
                script {
                    docker.withRegistry("https://${registryLogin}", "docker-hub-creds") {
                        docker.image("${imageURL}").pull()
                        docker.image("${imageURL}").inside() {
                            echo "Starting the build...."
                            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
                              branches: [[name: "${tagId}"]], 
                              userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: "bitbucket-creds", url: "https://bitbucket.example.com/scm/${repository_project_key}/${repoName}.git"]]])
                            sh """
                            mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout;
                            mvn clean install -DskipTests -Ptest
                            """
                        }
                    }
                }            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Configure the Jenkins webhook url in the bitbucket code
- Deploy it via a Jenkins pipeline based on the code checkout

#### Expected result

- Jenkins should deploy the code only based on TAG based code checkout. Not when the checkout to BRANCH.

#### Actual result

- Jenkins is triggering build for for both TAG and BRANCH based code push.

Already referred https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/blob/master/src/test/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/gwt/bdd/bitbucket-server/bitbucket-server-tag.feature but not much luck so far. Not sure how the build can be restricted to TAG based push only.

Answer (score 1):

Able to fix it by change the filter text to the below:

```
regexpFilterText: '$changes_ref_ids_0',
```

##### Working code should look something like:

```
def val = "Jenkins-Agent-01"
def registryLogin = "docker-hub.example.com"
def imageURL = "centos/devops-build:latest" 

pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label val
            customWorkspace "/opt/devops/workspace/${JOB_NAME}/${BUILD_NUMBER}"
        }
    }
    triggers {
        GenericTrigger(
            genericVariables: [
            [key: 'eventKey', value: '$.eventKey', defaultValue: 'null'],
            [key: 'tagId', value: '$.changes[0].refId', defaultValue: 'null'],
            [key: 'repoName', value: '$.repository.name', defaultValue: 'null'],
            [key: 'repository_slug', value: '$.repository.slug', defaultValue: 'null'],
            [key: 'repository_project_key', value: '$.repository.project.key', defaultValue: 'null'],
            [key: 'changes_ref_ids', value: '$.changes[?(@.ref.type == "TAG")].ref.id', defaultValue: 'null']
            ],
            causeString: 'Triggered By BitBucket',
            token: '',
            tokenCredentialId: '',
            printContributedVariables: true,
            printPostContent: true,
            silentResponse: false,
            regexpFilterText: '$changes_ref_ids_0',
            regexpFilterExpression: '^refs/tags/.*$'
        )
    }

    stages {
        stage('Display Payload') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh """
                    echo "Repo ref Id: ${changes_ref_ids_0)}"
                    echo "Repo Project Key: ${repository_project_key}"
                    """
                }            
            }
        }

        stage('Build Jar file') {
            steps {
                script {
                    docker.withRegistry("https://${registryLogin}", "docker-hub-creds") {
                        docker.image("${imageURL}").pull()
                        docker.image("${imageURL}").inside() {
                            echo "Starting the build...."
                            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
                              branches: [[name: "${tagId}"]], 
                              userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: "bitbucket-creds", url: "https://bitbucket.example.com/scm/${repository_project_key}/${repoName}.git"]]])
                            sh """
                            mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout;
                            mvn clean install -DskipTests -Ptest
                            """
                        }
                    }
                }            
            }
        }
    }
}
```